# Unix time conversion in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, unix-timestamp, categorical-data

I have a machine data set I need to analyze but in parsing an excel file from the line controller PC, the date info (which starts out formatted like "10/09/2020") ends up as what I assume is a unix time stamp that's longer than I've ever seen or can find an example of on SO (e.g. 1599696000000000000).

Efforts I have made to covert it have failed.  I am doing a python coursera program and the lecturer did say it is a difficult proposition as there's no standard way and none that I have tried have worked

Anyway, the excel file looks like this

```
Datum                WKZ_code    Time        Rad_t1   Not Important   Cut_Event
1599696000000000000  W03          00:00:00    100           250           /
1599696000000000000  W03          00:00:01    100           250           /
1599696000000000000  W03          00:00:02    100           250           /
1599696000000000000  W03          00:00:03    100           250           /
1599696000000000000  W03          00:00:04    100           250           /
1599696000000000000  W03          00:00:00    100           250           Speed Cut
```

I need to be able to bring the Datum column back to "DD/MM/YYYY" format otherwise my plots of the cut data fail as python seems to be unable to determine where to put them on a y axis.

What I tried that appeared the neatest solution was

```
pd.Timestamp.combine(pd.Timestamp.utcfromtimestamp(df['DATUM'][0]/1E9), pd.to_datetime(df['Time'][0]))
```

but that produced the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-b9d1b1186db5> in <module>
----> 1 pd.Timestamp.combine(pd.Timestamp.utcfromtimestamp(df['DATUM'][0]/1E9), pd.to_datetime(df['Time'][0]))

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.combine()

TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not Timestamp
```

A python developer in another department suggested:

```
df = pd.read_excel("tool W03 with cuts and dates.xlsx",
                   dtype=object)
df = df[['DATUM']]
df = df['DATUM']=(pd.to_datetime(df['DATUM'],unit='s')) 
df.head()
```

Which also threw an error around the unit, but I have been unable to come up with an a cure

```
pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime()

OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input 1599696000000000000 with the unit 's
```

If anyone can provide a solution i'd be very, very grateful. I've tried hard to keep to conventions with asking this, apologies in advance for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with default `unit='ns'` and convert times to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
print (df)
                Datum WKZ_code      Time  Rad_t1  Not Important  Cut_Event
0 2020-09-10 00:00:00      W03  00:00:00     100            250          /
1 2020-09-10 00:00:01      W03  00:00:01     100            250          /
2 2020-09-10 00:00:02      W03  00:00:02     100            250          /
3 2020-09-10 00:00:03      W03  00:00:03     100            250          /
4 2020-09-10 00:00:04      W03  00:00:04     100            250          /
5 2020-09-10 00:00:00      W03  00:00:00     100            250  Speed Cut
```

Comment: I'll try. If it turns out to be that simple i'll go away and cry before i do the plots.